# Visual Studio 2015 Not detecting my android device

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

I have opened a new Android Native-Activity project in Visual Studio 2015.But i am unable to run the project as on my visual studio 2015 i cant see my device listed,even after i select the ARM target. I have Samsung Galaxy S6 and my google USB driver is installed. The device get detected on my Android Studio and Eclipse. One thing i want to note that i have override the Android SDK path to different drive where i installed the SDK(D:/Android/sdk) under the visual studio settings than the default setting.

Comment: It seems the issue is Visual Studio does not recognise any device that have Lollipop installed.I have tried with Kitkat version installed device now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC (launch date: 10/27) introduces support for arm64 debugging when targeting the Android platform. Samsung Galaxy S6 is an arm64 device and not yet supported with Visual Studio 2015 RTM android development experience. You will find the install link for Update 1 RC on this [website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx).